# Spark: Difference between numPartitions in read.jdbc(..numPartitions..) and repartition(..numPartitions..)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

I'm perplexed between the behaviour of `numPartitions` parameter in the following methods:

1. `DataFrameReader.jdbc`
2. `Dataset.repartition`

The [official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@jdbc(url:String,table:String,columnName:String,lowerBound:Long,upperBound:Long,numPartitions:Int,connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) of `DataFrameReader.jdbc` say following regarding `numPartitions` parameter

> **numPartitions**:
>   the number of partitions. This, along with lowerBound (inclusive), upperBound (exclusive), form partition strides for generated WHERE clause expressions used to split the column columnName evenly.

And [official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) of `Dataset.repartition` say

> Returns a new Dataset that has exactly `numPartitions` partitions.

---

My current understanding:

1. The `numPartition` parameter in `DataFrameReader.jdbc` method controls the *degree of parallelism* in reading the data from database
2. The `numPartition` parameter in `Dataset.repartition` controls the *number of output files* that will be generated when this `DataFrame` would be written to disk

---

My questions:

1. If I read `DataFrame` via `DataFrameReader.jdbc` and then write it to disk (without invoking `repartition` method), then would there still be as many files in output as there would've been had I written out a `DataFrame` to disk after having invoked `repartition` on it?
2. If the answer to the above question is:

   - Yes: Then is it redundant to invoke `repartition` method on a `DataFrame` that was read using `DataFrameReader.jdbc` method (with `numPartitions` parameter)?
   - No: Then please correct the lapses in my understanding. Also in that case shouldn't the `numPartitions` parameter of `DataFrameReader.jdbc` method be called something like *'parallelism'*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: There is (almost) **no difference** in behaviour of `numPartitions` parameter in the two methods

---

**`read.jdbc(..numPartitions..)`**

Here, the `numPartitions` parameter controls:

1. **number of parallel connections** that would be made to the `MySQL` (or any other `RDBM`) **for reading the data** into `DataFrame`.
2. **Degree of parallelism** on all subsequent operations on the read `DataFrame` including **writing to disk** until `repartition` method is invoked on it

---

**`repartition(..numPartitions..)`**

Here `numPartitions` parameter controls the **degree of parallelism** that would be exhibited in **performing any operation** of the `DataFrame`, including **writing to disk**.

---

So basically the `DataFrame` obtained on reading `MySQL` table using `spark.read.jdbc(..numPartitions..)` method behaves the same (exhibits the same *degree of parallelism* in operations performed over it) as if it was *read* without *parallelism* and the `repartition(..numPartitions..)` method was invoked on it afterwards (obviously with same value of `numPartitions`)

---

To answer to exact questions:

> If I read DataFrame via DataFrameReader.jdbc and then write it to disk
>   (without invoking repartition method), then would there still be as
>   many files in output as there would've been had I written out a
>   DataFrame to disk after having invoked repartition on it?

Yes

Assuming that the *read* task had been *parallelized* by providing appropriate parameters (`columnName`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound` & `numPartitions`), *all* operations on the resulting `DataFrame` **including write** will be performed in parallel. Quoting the [official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) here:

> numPartitions: The maximum number of partitions that can be used for parallelism in table reading and writing. This also determines the maximum number of concurrent JDBC connections. If the number of partitions to write exceeds this limit, we decrease it to this limit by calling coalesce(numPartitions) before writing.

---

> Yes: Then is it redundant to invoke repartition method on a DataFrame that was read using DataFrameReader.jdbc method (with numPartitions parameter)?

Yes

Unless you invoke the other variations of `repartition` method (the ones that take `columnExprs` param), invoking `repartition` on such a `DataFrame` (with same `numPartitions`) parameter is redundant. However, I'm not sure if forcing same *degree of parallelism* on an *already-parallelized* `DataFrame` also invokes **shuffling** of data among `executors` unnecessarily. Will update the answer once I come across it.

Comment: Also see: [Order of column arguments in `repartition` vs `partitionBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48356425/3679900)