# Spark: Order of column arguments in repartition vs partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

Methods taken into consideration (`Spark 2.2.1`):

1. `DataFrame.repartition` (the two implementations that take `partitionExprs: Column*` parameters)
2. `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy`

### Note: This question doesn't ask the difference between these methods

From [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@partitionBy(colNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[T]) of `partitionBy`:

> If specified, the output is laid out on the file system similar to `Hive`'s *partitioning scheme*. As an example, when we partition a `Dataset` by year and then month, the *directory layout* would look like:
>
> - year=2016/month=01/
> - year=2016/month=02/

From this, I infer that the **order of column arguments** will decide the directory layout; hence it is *relevant*.

From [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(partitionExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) of `repartition`:

> Returns a new `Dataset` partitioned by the given *partitioning expressions*, using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` as number of partitions. The resulting `Dataset` is *hash partitioned*.

As per my current understanding, `repartition` decides the **degree of parallelism** in handling the `DataFrame`. With this definition, behaviour of `repartition(numPartitions: Int)` is straightforward but the same can't be said about the other two implementations of `repartition` that take `partitionExprs: Column*` arguments.

---

All things said, my doubts are following:

- Like `partitionBy` method, is the **order of column** inputs relevant in `repartition` method too?
- If the answer to above question is

  - **No**: Does each *chunk* extracted for parallel execution contain the same data as would have been in each *group* had we run a `SQL` query with `GROUP BY` on same columns?
  - **Yes**: Please explain the behaviour of `repartition(columnExprs: Column*)` method
- What is the relevance of having both `numPartitions: Int` and `partitionExprs: Column*` arguments in the third implementation of `repartition`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only similarity between these two methods are their names. There are used for different things and have different mechanics so you shouldn't compare them at all.

That being said, `repartition` shuffles data using:

- With `partitionExprs` it uses hash partitioner on the columns used in the expression using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`.
- With `partitionExprs` and `numPartitions` it does the same as the previous one, but overriding `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`.
- With `numPartitions` it just rearranges data using `RoundRobinPartitioning`.

> the order of column inputs relevant in repartition method too?

It is. `hash((x, y))` is in general not the same as `hash((y, x))`.

```py
df = (spark.range(5, numPartitions=4).toDF("x")
    .selectExpr("cast(x as string)")
    .crossJoin(spark.range(5, numPartitions=4).toDF("y")))

df.repartition(4, "y", "x").rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
```

```
[8, 6, 9, 2]
```

```py
df.repartition(4, "x", "y").rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
```

```
[6, 4, 3, 12]
```

> Does each chunk extracted for parallel execution contain the same data as would have been in each group had we run a SQL query with GROUP BY on same columns?

Depending on what is the exact question.

- Yes. `GROUP BY` with the same set of columns will result in the same logical distribution of keys over partitions.
- No. Hash partitioner [can map multiple keys to the same partition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/6910411). `GROUP BY` "sees" only the actual groups.

Related [How to define partitioning of DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30995699/6910411)

Answer (score 1):

Before answering this question, let me clear you about some concepts in spark.

**block**: These are physically mapped to HDFS Folder and are capable of storing sub blocks and parquet/* files.

**parquet**: data store compressed files, commonly used in HDFS clusters to store data.

now coming to the answer.

Repartition(number_of_partitions, *columns) : this will create parquet files with data shuffled and sorted on the distinct combination values of the columns provided. therefore order of column doesn't make any difference here. you can provide any order in the background spark will get all the possible value of these columns, sort them and arrange the data in the files which will sum to the **number_of_partitions** .

PartionBy(*columns): this is slightly different from repartition. this will create blocks or folders in the HDFS with distinct values of columns provided in the parameters. so suppose:

Col A = [1,2,3,4,5]

while writing the table HDFS it will create the folder names 
colA-1

colA-2

colA-3
.
.
.
and if you provide two columns then

colA-1/
       colB-1
       colB-2
       colB-3
       .
       .

colA-2/

colA-3/
.
.
.

and inside this it will store parquet files which will have data sorted on the parent column value. the number of files in this folder will be fixed by (bucketBy) attribute which will further suggest the maximum number of files in each folder. this is only available in pyspark 2.3 and in scala 1.6 onward.