# Spark task runs on only one executor

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Hello everyone first and foremost i'm aware of the existence of this thread, [Task is running on only one executor in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425983/task-is-running-on-only-one-executor-in-spark).
However this is not my case as i'm using `repartition(n)` on my dataframe.
Basically i'm loading a DataFrame by fetching data from an ElasticSearch index through Spark as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("elastic") \
    .master("yarn")\
    .config('spark.submit.deployMode','client')\
    .config("spark.jars",pathElkJar) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

es_reader = (spark.read
        .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
        .option("es.read.field.include",includeFieldsString)
        .option("es.query",q)
        .option("es.nodes",elasticClusterIP)
        .option("es.port",port)
        .option("es.resource",indexNameTable)
        .option("es.nodes.wan.only" , 'true')
        .option("es.net.ssl", 'true')
        .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true")
        .option("es.net.http.auth.user" ,elkUser )
        .option("es.net.http.auth.pass" , elkPassword)
        .option("es.read.metadata", "false")
        .option("es.read.field.as.array.include","system_auth_hostname")
        #.option("es.mapping.exclude", "index")
        #.option("es.mapping.id", "_id")
        #.option("es.read.metadata._id","_id")
        #.option("delimiter", ",")
        #.option("inferSchema","true")
        #.option("first_row_is_header","true")
        )

df = es_reader.load()
```

YARN correctly adds by default 2 executors to my application as i did not specify else. DF is not partitioned when loading data from ElasticSearch therefore i ran the following to check executor behavior:

```
df = df.repartition(2)
print('Number of partitions: {}'.format(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()))
>> Number of partitions: 2
df.count()
```

I expected to see from Spark UI both executor working on the `count()` task, however i get a strange behavior where i have three task completed, without repartitioning it's two task for an action, where the first and longer one is ran by only one executor as you can see in the following image:
[Count()-twoExecutor-twoPartitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGeis.png).

Things work as expected if i save and load from an hive table already partitioned in two (OS:linux/windows):

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').format("parquet").partitionBy('OS').saveAsTable('test_executors')
df2 = spark.read.load("path")
df2.count()
```

In this case i get the following:
[Count()-twoExecutor-twoPartitions_loadFromHiveTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3SRy.png)

Where i get the desired behavior of two executor cuncurrently working on the `count()` task.
The problem seems to be lying in the `repartition(n)` which i think correctly partitions the DF, i checked with `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` but **doesn't** parallelize work amongst executors.
If necessary i can provide the details to the tasks in the attached images. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find what caused this? I have a similar issue where I read directly from ES into an RDD. Reading is in multiple threads and I can see multiple executors busy. However, after that I repartition and do some more work, which seems to be executed on a single executor.

Comment: it's been a long time but maybe the first task is just the single executor doing the repartition and then it actually works fine. I really can't remember sorry!